# How is it possible that Rachael Rosen slept with several bounty hunters?

Tags: do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

At the beginning of *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?*, we learn that Rachael Rosen is an android who had received fake memories, leading her to believe she was the actual niece of Eldon Rosen. Deckard asks Eldon if she knew she was an android, to which he replies no.

Then, after sleeping with Deckard, Rachael says she has slept with many bounty hunters before, so they wouldn't be able to continue with their task.

> 'No bounty hunter ever has gone on,' Rachael said. 'After being with me. Except one. A very
>   cynical man. Phil Resch. And he's nutty; he works out in left field on his own.'
>
> 'I see' Rick said. He felt numb. Completely. Throughout his entire body.
>
> 'But this trip we're taking,' Rachael said, 'won't be wasted, because you're going to meet a
>   wonderful, spiritual man.'
>
> 'Roy Baty,' he said. 'Do you know all of them?'
>
> 'I knew all of them, when they still existed. I know three, now, We tried to stop you this
>   morning, before you started out with Dave Holden's list. I tried again, just before Polokov
>   reached you. But then after that I had to wait.'
>
> 'Until I broke down,' he said. 'And had to call you.'
>
> 'Luba Luft and I had been close, very close friends for almost two years. What did you think
>   of her? Did you like her?'
>
> 'I liked her.'
>
> 'But you killed her.'
>
> 'Phil Resch killed her.'
>
> 'Oh, so Phil accompanied you back to the opera house. We didn't know that; our
>   communications broke down about then. We knew just that she had been killed; we naturally 
>   assumed by you.'
>
> 'From Dave's notes,' he said, 'I think I can still go ahead and retire Roy Baty. But maybe not
>   Irmgard Baty,' And not Pris Stratton, he thought. Even now; even knowing this. 'So all that
>   took place at the hotel,' he said, 'consisted of a -'
>
> 'The association,' Rachael said, 'wanted to reach the bounty hunters here and in the Soviet
>   Union. This seemed to work for reasons which we do not fully understand. Our limitation
>   again, I guess.'

Were Eldon and Rachael lying, which means Rachael knew she was an android all along? Or have her memories been constantly replaced? Otherwise, how is it possible that Rachael didn't know she was an android, but was working for the Association as a tool against bounty hunters?

Comment: Aren't these the kinds of questions that Philip Dick deliberately left indeterminate in order to produce an unsettled mood in the reader? At least, that's how I've read his novels.

Comment: @Reinstate and OP: the [philip-k-dick] tag is not appropriate for this question. Please read [our policy on author tag vs franchise tag vs work tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/98028)